# Accessing a media file created with Cordova plugin for local use in Meteor script with gifshotJS library

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

to make my question short and simple:

How can I access the mediaFile generated by cordova-plugin-media-capture's function `capture.captureVideo()` and convert it with gifShot JS' `createGIF()`function into a GIF on an Android device?

I ran into the problem, that neither the fullPath (`file:/`URI), nor the localURL (`cdvfile://`) of the generated mediaFile are permitted for the use, if I directly give one of them as path for the video file for gifshot, I receive following message:

> Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

I know that the file plugin successfully creates the videos (I can see them in the galery, so they are saved on the device permanently).
And I also know that gifShot works with mp4 videos as I already created a folder inside the project directory containing a video which it rendered correctly. I also know that sadly JavaScript normally is not permitted to gain access to files on a device/PC, but isn't there a workaround provided with Cordova?

Can someone briefly explain me, how I could access the saved file? Do I need the cordova plugins "cordova-plugin-file" and "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" and how do I use them?

My code:
*Javascript:*

```
import gifshot from 'gifshot';

Template.gifshotTest.rendered = function () {
    var $$ = Dom7;
    var myapp = new Framework7();
    };

Template.gifshotTest.events({
    'click .gifShotUpload': function () {
        Meteor.call("console", "Button clicked");

        // capture callback
        var captureSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
            path = mediaFiles[0].localURL;
            Meteor.call("console", mediaFiles[0]);
            gifshot.createGIF({video: path}, function(obj) {
                Meteor.call("console", "---> gifshot obj:");
                Meteor.call("console", obj);
                    if (!obj.error) {
                        var image = obj.image;
                        $('.giffy').attr("src", image);
                        Meteor.call("console", image);
                    }
            });
        };

// capture error callback
        var captureError = function (error) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
        };

// start video capture
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1, duration: 5, quality: 1});
    }
});
```

*Console logs*

> I20160421-15:25:36.283(2)? Button clicked
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.158(2)? null
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.166(2)? { name: 'VID_20160421_152544.mp4',
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.167(2)?   localURL: 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160421_152544.mp4',
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.167(2)?   type: 'video/mp4',
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.168(2)?   lastModified: null,
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.168(2)?   lastModifiedDate: 1461245147000,
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.169(2)?   size: 461498,
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.169(2)?   start: 0,
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.169(2)?   end: 0,
>
> I20160421-15:25:42.170(2)?   fullPath: 'file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160421_152544.mp4' }
>
> I20160421-15:25:44.656(2) (android:http://localhost:12680/:0) Cross-origin  image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

*Included Cordova Plugins (Cordova Version 3.8.3)*:

cordova-plugin-file@4.1.1

cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1

cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.2.0

Thanks to everyone who helps me understanding the way Cordova and other libraries handle files on a device.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is successfully stored in device, you can open the same use using [cordova-fileopener-plugin](http://%20If%20the%20file%20is%20successfully%20stored%20in%20device,%20you%20can%20open%20the%20same%20use%20using%20cordova-fileopener-plugin). I would also suggest you to update your cordova version as the one you are using is too old

Comment: I don't want to open the file itself. I want `gifshot.createGIF()` to use it to create a GIF out of it.

Comment: @cscholz if u wanna make gif out of it using gifshot, then you gotta convert the image to base64 image using cordova file plugin and then feed base64 image to createGIF method. check this link - http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova

Comment: @Ghandi Does it also work with videos like it is discribed in your link?

Basically I want this to happen:
Capture video -> access it from the file system -> use it in gifShot to create a GIF -> send GIF to server

Comment: @cscholz it should work for videos as well provided the video size is not too big which may result in memory issues. But if you are able to get the video created in device and follow the link, you are through. Hope is helps